# Calculating time elapsed from current time in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, time, duration

In my program, a user fills out a userform which automatically generates the info and time that it was filled out on another excel sheet. I would like to use VBA to calculate the duration from the original entry time from the form to the current time. I don't understand why my code isn't working. When I try to use it, the duration keeps coming up as zero. I am not sure what I need to subtract from "Now()" in order to make this work and give me an actual value.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cmdOkUpdate_Click()

Dim length As Date

length = Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss")

strBOL = txtBOL.Value
strID = txtID.Value
details = txtDet.Value
opt = lbxOption.Value
currtime = time()
today = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")
emp = TextBox1.Value
dur = Format(Now() - currtime, "hh:mm:ss")

If NoFill = True Then
    cellFill = ""
ElseIf NoFill = False Then
    With Sheet5

    .Range("A1").Value = "Time"
    .Range("B1").Value = "Date"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Location"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Category"
    .Range("E1").Value = "BOL"
    .Range("f1").Value = "Trailer #"
    .Range("g1").Value = "Details"
    .Range("H1").Value = "EE Name"
    .Range("I1").Value = "Duration"
    
    .Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
    .Range("A2").Value = currtime
    .Range("B2").Value = today
    .Range("C2").Value = spot
    .Range("D2").Value = opt
    .Range("E2").Value = strBOL
    .Range("F2").Value = strID
    .Range("G2").Value = details
    .Range("H2").Value = emp
    .Range("I2").Value = dur
    
    .Columns("A:I").AutoFit
    
    End With

    If Not IsEmpty(opt) Then
        cellFill = opt & " " & vbCrLf & "BOL (last 5 digits): " & strBOL & " " & vbCrLf & "Trailer # " & strID & " " & vbCrLf & "Details: " & details & " " & vbCrLf & "EE Name: " & emp & " " & vbCrLf
        ActiveCell.Value = cellFill
        Call RealTimeTracker
    End If
    
End If


Unload Me
Sheet1.Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: `currtime = time()` - what is that?

Comment: Why are you using `Format()`? This function returns a STRING. You want to work with numerical values. `Now()` is a numerical value as it is, don't convert it to a string.

Comment: `today = Format(Now(), "MM/DD/YYYY")` can be simplified to just `today = Date`.

Comment: Anyways, elapsed time can be obtained by using the `Timer()` function. `Dim t As Single` _(or `As Double` for more precision)_, then set the current timer to the var `t = Timer`. Then when you need elapsed time: `Debug.Print Timer - t` _(`Format()` would be okay in this area, just not with calculations. Should have been more clear on that in last comment)_ Either method works whether using `Now()` or this. This would just be the number of seconds elapsed, which could be converted as necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would like to find the elapsed time from a time that is already entered on my sheet. That time comes from the currtime = time () which auto-generates the time the user filled out the form. So I am interested in the time elapsed from the time the user filled out the form to now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Leah, your code is actually working. If you try this (adapted from your code), you'll see it work:

```vb
Sub test()
    currtime = Time()
    waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    While Now() < waitTill
        DoEvents
    Wend
    dur = Format(Now() - currtime, "hh:mm:ss")
    MsgBox (dur)
End Sub
```

The problem you are having is that `dur` is too close to `currtime`, thus, *the actual time elapsed is 0*.

You can try placing it lower in the code, like this:

```vb
If NoFill = True Then
    cellFill = ""
ElseIf NoFill = False Then
    With Sheet5

    '...
    .Range("I2").Value = Format(Now() - currtime, "hh:mm:ss")
    '...
    End With

    '...
    
End If
```

**However**, I don't think it will make a difference, because the code doesn't seem to be doing anything 'complicated' enough to take more than a second.